# QFuture Help, Threading C++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt

So i have found out that some issues on my UI program are happening because im not making use of threading.

I had a look and from what i can see in the documentation QFuture seemed like what i needed, am i right in thinking that this is used when you have a function and you just want to run it in a thread?

right so assuming im correct on that i go through the documentation and type code shown in all the examples and basically it just does not work at all...

UI.cpp

```
#include <QFuture>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentRun>
#include "something.h"
void UI::button_click()
{
     something s;
     QFuture<int> result = QtConcurrent::run(s.heavyFunction());

     result.waitForFinished();
}
```

something.cpp

```
int something::heavyFunction()
{
     // heavy code here
     return 42;
}
```

ok obviously this isnt real code but theres nothing different here than in my actual code but i get the following error

```
error C2780: 'QFuture<T> QtConcurrent::run(T (__cdecl *)(Param1),const Arg1 &)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided
```

and it says this error about 7 times basically saying 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 arguments expected 1 provided?

i got this code from a number of examples so what am i missing any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`QtConcurrent::run`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html) takes a function and arguments to be passed to that function. In the case of a member function, you would need something like

```
something s;
QFuture<int> result = QtConcurrent::run(&s, &something::heavyFunction);
```

Member functions such as `something::heavyFunction` take an implicit parameter of type `T*`, where `T` is the type that has the member function (`something` in this case). `QtConcurrent::run` seems to deal with this by taking the instance as first parameter, and the member function as second. This seems unnatural and counter intuitive, and at odds with e.g. `std::async`.

Comment: ok iv tried this but now i get the error term does not evaluate to a function taking one argument ...

Comment: my `something s;` is declared as a member variable though i assume this makes no difference ?

Comment: @AngryDuck it should make no difference. You just need the address of the instance you want the member function to be run in. Bu the member function you pass must be a member of `something`.

Comment: hmm i thought so, i have included `<QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentRun>' and `<QFuture>` and included your exact code and i get the error mentioned above?

Comment: @AngryDuck Ah OK, could you try `QtConcurrent::run(&s, &something::heavyFunction)`?

Comment: @AngryDuck are you sure `something::heavyFunction` returns `int` and not `void`?